# Laravel whereNotIn is not working when null values encountered

Tags: laravel-8

I have a table (orders) where I have a 'status' column which allows null values. Here is an example of the table.

| id | status |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 'Draft' |
| 2 | 'Draft' |
| 3 | null |
| 4 | 'Draft' |

when I write query like

```
 Order::whereIn('status',['Draft'])->count()
```

it gives me expected number which is 3.

But when I revert the query like.

```
Order::whereNotIn('status',['Draft'])->count()
```

It don't give me the expected answer which is 1. Rather it gives me always 0.
Can you please help me out?

Answer (score 1):

Give it a try:

```
DB::connection()->enableQueryLog();

Order::whereNotIn('status',['Draft'])->orWhereNull('status')->count();

DB::getQueryLog();
```

Comment: Yes it works, But my question was why the query is not working. Since it seems logically correct

Comment: look like condition not detect null value

Comment: null value actually is a value for mysql...yeah sounds weird and to query nulls you need to explicitly tell the is null condition. you can enable the query log and see the generated SQL. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/working-with-null.html

Comment: look like laravel eloquent where function not detect null , not from mysql

Comment: updated the response, feel free to check the generated sql with those two lines.